# Adding months to a date value in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I am trying the following code and getting the sql date time overflow exception.....The problem lies in the Gold part...rest to i.e. Silver and Premium work fine....When in Gold part I try to add certain number of months to a date time field I don't know what action is performed as when i check it through Message box the ren_date has value "12:00:00 AM" rather than the new date value after adding 6 months in mem_date value....

```
        Dim ren_date, mem_date As Date
        Dim renmon As String

        mem_date = TxtMemDate.Text

        ' checks the type of membership and adds corresponding number of years to the membership date and stores in renewal date

        If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Silver" Then
            ren_date = mem_date.AddMonths(3)
            renmon = ren_date.ToString("MMMM")
        ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Premium" Then
            ren_date = mem_date.AddYears(1)
            renmon = ren_date.ToString("MMMM")
        ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Gold" Then
            ren_date = mem_date.AddMonths(6)
            renmon = ren_date.ToString("MMMM")
        End If

        MsgBox(mem_date)
        MsgBox(ren_date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your issue is actually here:

```
mem_date = TxtMemDate.Text
```

It may be that the `String` you're trying to coerce to a `Date` here isn't in the right format. Try putting a breakpoint after this line and go through with a debugger to experiment.

---

Here's another thing to try: maybe your `ComboBox1.SelectedItem` does not exactly match the string "Gold." Add an `Else` block to your `If` and put in there something like

```
MsgBox("*" & ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() & "*")
```

This should reveal if there are, for example, leading or trailing spaces around the item's text.

Comment: Whichever Date Value i try...It works for the other two options i.e. Premium and Silver....like if i try 12/12/2011, Premium adds an year and the value becomes 12/12/2012, Silver adds 3 months and value becomes 3/12/2012, but Gold option generates 12:00:00 AM

Comment: @user944591: Am I correct in saying there's more code you're not sharing? I'm having trouble seeing how this difference could arise given the code you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

This code performs as expected

```
Dim ren_date, mem_date As DateTime
Dim renmon As String = ""

If DateTime.TryParse(TxtMemDate.Text, mem_date) Then 'convert text to date
    ' checks the type of membership and adds corresponding number of years to the membership date and stores in renewal date
    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString = "Silver" Then
        ren_date = mem_date.AddMonths(3)
        renmon = ren_date.ToString
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString = "Premium" Then
        ren_date = mem_date.AddYears(1)
        renmon = ren_date.ToString
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString = "Gold" Then
        ren_date = mem_date.AddMonths(6)
        renmon = ren_date.ToString
    End If
    Debug.WriteLine(renmon)
Else
    Debug.WriteLine("Date entered is not correct format")
End If
```